# Eponymous -- Just for people?

Tags: meaning

Can "eponymous" be applied to a thing named after something that is not a person? For example, as we can say McAfee's eponymous anti virus software (named after John McAfee), can we also talk about Google's eponymous search engine or Pepsi's eponymous drink?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See [Oxford's definition](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eponymous):

> 1.(Of a person) giving their name to something:
>   *"the eponymous hero of the novel"*
>
> 1.1(Of a thing) named after a particular person or group:
>   *"their eponymous debut LP"*

Comment: I think the OED means a "group of people" here, which probably doesn't quite answer my question. The examples are in reference to products being "eponymous" to the company that makes them.