# Equivalent of eponym for short story/compendium?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a specific word for the short story whose title is also the title of a compendium of short stories containing that one? The closest I can come up with is `eponym` but that doesn't feel quite right.

On the one hand, the compendium is named after the short story, so that sounds like it fits the definition of [eponym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous):

```
of, relating to, or being the person or thing for whom or which something is named
```

But [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326692/eponymous-just-for-people) seems unanswered/debatable as to whether or not eponymous can apply to something other than a person.

Is there a word other than eponymous that better fills the blank below?

```
In the ____ short story of Wallace's "Oblivion", we meet Randall, who...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia entry on [Wallace's *Oblivian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivion:_Stories) uses *title* here -

> In the same essay, Tracey further develops his thoughts on the **title story**, "Oblivion," which raises questions about what reality is, and what is real.

Using *title story* rather than *title short story* feels more natural.

This is certainly common usage in with respect to music.  For example, we would all say "Help! is the title track of the Beatles' album Help!".

Comment: Oh wow, the answer was *on* the wikipedia page I had been looking at. Sheesh... and thanks!